# calling a webservice that returns xml from ios with wdsl2objc

Tags: ios, xml, ios6, wsdl2objc

I'm making an app that searches a database via a webservice call that uses "login" and returns an xml "string".

The wdsl for this call is as follows:

```
<s:element name="PerformGlobalSearch">
  <s:complexType>
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="searchString" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="s:int"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="s:string"/>
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>

<s:element name="PerformGlobalSearchResponse">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PerformGlobalSearchResult">
       <s:complexType mixed="true">
         <s:sequence>
           <s:any/>
         </s:sequence>
       </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="s:int"/>
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="s:string"/>
   </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
```

I've generated code using wsdl2objc and it seems to work fine. I just need to know how to accsess the xml returned.

If I `NSLog` the responsdata in the "webserviceSvc.m" class it prints the xml.
However, it then returns an object generated by wsdl2objc "PerformeGlobalSearchResponse".
I managed to receive this in code but I can't seem to accsess the xml that it should contain.

```
-(void) processResponse : (WebServiceSoapBindingResponse *)soapResponse {
NSArray *responseBodyParts = soapResponse.bodyParts;

id bodyPart;
@try{
   bodyPart = [responseBodyParts objectAtIndex:0];
}
...

else if([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[xxxWebServiceSvc_PerformeGlobalSearchResponse class]])    {
xxxWebServiceSvc_PerformGlobalSearchResponse* SearchResponse = bodyPart;

NSLog(@"Test: %@", SearchResponse.PerformeGlobalSearchResult);
}
```

I've tried lots of diferent ways. 
I need to access the xml and I need to parse it. Parsing I think I've managed while trying diferent solutions.

But how do I accsess the xml? How do I convert PerformGlobalSearchResult to an xml Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to my problem ended up being to change the SOAP code generated so it returned what I needed.

It turned out it got sett up by the WSDL and wsdl2objc to return the worng variable type.
I changed it around and ended up using a Dictionary as the return value, because that was a predefined type that was not used.
I was then able to prase it with no dificulty.